# C# - OpenXML SDK - How to get the IDs of the Master Slides for an empty presentation?

Tags: c#, openxml, slide, presentation

If the presentation is empty or has just one slide the code below (and that's expected) returns 1 ID, but the presentation has 10+ masters. How can I get the full list of existing masters in an any presentation?

```
        static string[,] GetSlideMasterIds(string templatePath)
            {
                List<string[]> slideMasterIdList = new List<string[]>();

                using (PresentationDocument presentationDocument = PresentationDocument.Open(templatePath, false))
                {
                    // Get the main presentation part
                    PresentationPart presentationPart = presentationDocument.PresentationPart;

                    // Get the slide id list
                    SlideIdList slideIdList = presentationPart.Presentation.SlideIdList;

                    // Iterate through slide ids
                    foreach (SlideId slideId in slideIdList.Elements<SlideId>())
                    {
                        string slideIdValue = slideId.Id.ToString();
                        string relationshipId = slideId.RelationshipId;

                        slideMasterIdList.Add(new string[] { slideIdValue, relationshipId });
                    }
                }

                // Convert the list to a two-dimensional array
                string[,] slideMasterIds = new string[slideMasterIdList.Count, 2];
                for (int i = 0; i < slideMasterIdList.Count; i++)
                {
                    slideMasterIds[i, 0] = slideMasterIdList[i][0]; // Slide ID
                    slideMasterIds[i, 1] = slideMasterIdList[i][1]; // Relationship ID
                }

                return slideMasterIds;
            }
```

I've also tryed to get the IDs by using the relationship between Slide Layouts and Master Slides, but there was a mess. Any suggestions?